# Detect change Orientation among Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, orientation, android-orientation

I had

- `Fragment A` already `addToBackStack()`.
- `Fragment B` not `addToBackStack()`.

When Im in `Fragment A`. I can detect change orientation by using `onSaveInstanceState` & `onViewStateRestored` method.

But I can not be successful when I'm in `Fragment B`. I tried to detect change orientation by using `onSaveInstanceState` & `onViewStateRestored` method also but not worked.

It means It always detect change orientation in `Fragment A` although I'm in `Fragment B`. (Can not recognized changed orientation in `Fragment B`)

People who know how I can detect change orientation in `Fragment B` without detect change orientation of `Fragment A` in this case?

Please help me,

Thanks,

p/s : The following code detail how to transfer from `Fragment A` to `Fragment B`

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fr_content_activity_fitness, mFm)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I find out the answer for my question.

Since I used The following code detail how to transfer `from Fragment A to Fragment B`

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fr_content_activity_fitness, mFm)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

While Fragment A already added to `BackStack`.

So the context now only is `Fragment A`.

To detect change orientation in `Fragment B` as above question detail, is changed to the following code, it worked :

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fr_content_activity_fitness, mFm)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Used `add` instead of `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

Detect orientation:

```
    mCurrentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

Handle orientation changes:

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mCurrentOrientation = newConfig.orientation;
}
```

All this works in fragments well.

Comment: Sorry u don't understand my question. I added this code to `Fragment B`, and changed orientation in `Fragment B`. But the methods in `Fragment A` was still called, in `Fragment B` is not called.